Semantic Issue (Xcode): 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App extension)
I created new target, NotificationServiceExtension.
I add this end of my pod file.
target 'NotificationServiceExtension' do end
I tried to set Require Only App-Extension Safe API to NO. Got error about this
First, error is abour share_plus, when i update it, error is fixed, but different plugin shows error next time


SOLUTION:
Use this
target 'YourNotificationServiceExtension' do inhibit_all_warnings! use_frameworks! end
